# C# embedded Db with concurrency and mono support

Tags: .net, database, concurrency, mono

I am writing a service that needs a embedded database to store basic info (id, date inserted, last updated and a large string of my actual data that i will return). I will have multiple threads reading different rows at the same time and at least 1 thread doing updates to rows at the same time. I would prefer the option of more than one thread doing updates but i can service with just one thread been able to do updates.  Basically this is a caching service but generally 99% of my data will be in the cache and i can have a single thread populating what is missing as it is a cache for a service that limits the number of requests per minute hence caching all the data.

I want to be able to run this on windows or linux so dotnet and mono support is a must but almost all embedded databases I have looked at don't support concurrency and that is a must for me. Object database or sql database does not both me as long as it integrates well with dotnet.

I am hoping someone has some experience in a similar situation with needing a embedded database with concurrency support.  Also i would prefer a free (cost wise) database if at all possible as this is just a personal project for home at this stage.

I have looked at a number of databases (STSdb, SQL CE, Firebird, a heap of open source ones on codeplex) but they either don't work on mono/linux or don't seems to have concurrency support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) it't supported on Mono (http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite) and it has concurrency support, quote from the [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) question 5 :

> Q:Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same
>   application access a single database file at the same time?
>
> A:Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
>   Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only
>   one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in
>   time, however.

Comment: I am currently looking at SQLite. Only thing i will point aout about its concurrency is this. Can't find it in doco now but one of the pages i was reading says that threads are bad and while it does support concurrency it seems to do it by limiting the instance to one thread internally.

Comment: That said having it internally limited to one thread in the DB may not be a big issue as DB should be quite fast. Don't you need different DLL or somethign for sqlite depending on the OS? So far this seems like the best option

Comment: Yes, you will need different binaries (*.dll or *.so) look at the Prerequisites on mono project SQLite page. I am not aware of such "one thread" limitation (http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=MultiThreading , http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/56.aspx)

Comment: Form that link "The ADO.NET wrapper has built-in retry and timeout mechanisms to handle these scenarios, but if you are using multiple threads and attempt to mix a read with a write, or a write with a read, you're going to hit a deadlock." I will have a lot of reads coming in while i could be writing that is the only thing that has me worried about sqlite at this stage.

Comment: I don't have much expirience with SQLite in multithreaded environment, sorry. But I really think that SQLite is your best bet

Comment: Thanks for the answers it is the best option i have found so i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are we talking about?
Does it need to be a database?

If its just one 'table' could you just write a small layer that uses the file system, one folder per row named id-createdDate-updatedDate and just throw a text file in there? you'd still get concurent reads, and limited writes

Comment: I will have about 100k rows.  I was going to use the filesystem to store the files as i mostly find things by the ID but i also need to be able to quickly find records not updated in the last week based on a date stored on the record etc so i thought a DB would be better. (file DB is fine as long as it has some sort of index)

Answer (score 0):

One change since this question was first asked is you can now use the .NET async and await features so that not being able to do concurrent writes is not as likely to cause a bottle neck.